# How to share/pass a variable with application properties and pom file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a multi module spring-boot project, before integration tests of my app, I start another child module (which is Stub made by another spring boot app) You can see it is attached to "pre-integration-test" and **it is working fine** finally.

```
 Parent Pom
|   
|----myRealApp module(spring boot app)
|----stub module(This is also a spring-boot app)
```

My question is, is there a way to randomize And share this port (not fixed to 8090), so concurrent builds on Jenkins server can run tests and not fail because address is in use already.

I know I can generate random numbers/ports in spring properties file. But couldn't find a way to pass it to Pom.

**application-test.properties** of myRealApp:

```
 stub.port=8090
 stub.url=http://localhost:${stub.port}/stub/api/v1/domains/
```

Pom of myRealApp:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${spring.boot.mainclass}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start-stub</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--server.port=8090</argument>
                        </arguments>
                        <mainClass>io.swagger.Stub</mainClass>
                        <classesDirectory>../my-stub/target/classes</classesDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: I'm not clear why you need a stub app for testing? Usually in Spring Boot it's really easy to write unit/integration tests etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Keep saying "Spring Boot it's really easy to write tests" is not solving any problem. MockRestServerServer does configure the RestTemplate with a custom ClientHttpRequestFactory, thus overrides my custom requestFactory, which has settings for timeouts and authentication. Can you please explain how do you plan to test these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that via jenkins [Port Allocator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Port+Allocator+Plugin)

Once you assign the port (lets say `HTTP_PORT`), then you can pass this as command line

```
-Dstub.port=$HTTP_PORT
```

Comment: Didn't actually use this approach, but its the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to randomize at all. My suggestion is to parametrize the server port in the POM and application-test.properties files, and set a value based upon some Jenkins-provided variable: For example, `BUILD_NUMBER`, which is incremented on every build and thus uniqueness is guranteed.

However, there is a problem about this: You also need to enclose the port number within *valid boundaries*: TCP ports must be within 1024 and 65535, however `BUILD_NUMBER` is not limited at all.

How to cope with this? I think a simple Ant task bound to the `initialize` phase could read the `BUILD_NUMBER` value, apply it a simple formula `1024+(BUILD_NUMBER % 64512)`, and set it as the definitive port number variable, which is the one you will reference in the POM and application-test.properties files.